# In PrimeNG, how do I set a border color for the p-calendar component when no data is entered?

Tags: calendar, primeng, angular14, primeng-calendar

I'm using Angular 14 and PrimeNG 14. I have a p-calendar component that I would like to style with a red border color if the user has not entered a value. I have

```
            <p-calendar
                            [showIcon]="true" 
                            [ngClass]="{'border-red-500': this.submitted && this.form.get('myDate')?.hasError('required')}"
                            formControlName="myDate"></p-calendar>
```

However, this does not do anything to change the style.  What is the proper way to change the border color of the p-calendar component given certain conditions?

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Border should be applied to input not p-calendar. Change your code to set inputStyleClass as below.

<p-calendar [showIcon]="true" [inputStyleClass]="this.submitted && this.form.get('myDate')?.hasError('required') ? 'red-bar': ''"                          formControlName="myDate">

I have created stackblitz for this.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-vjtcnp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Or even with your implementation, you can simply change your class definition to

```
.border-red-500 .p-inputtext {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

write the style in global styles.css.

Comment: This results in a compile error.  "inputSTyleClass" is underlined with a compile error, which is "Type '{ "border-red-500": boolean | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'string'."

Comment: @Dave I have updated code & added stackblitz solution. Also gave alternate way with original code in the question